# Removing a row from the table and re indexing the table

Tags: javascript, html

I'm trying to create a button to put in the each row of a table to remove that row

the table row it self will be created by javascript on the runtime

```
function createrow(){

   document.getElementById('totaltd').innerHTML = total;

   var table = document.getElementById('baskettbl');
   var rowCount = table.rows.length;
   var row = table.insertRow(rowCount);
   var cell2 = row.insertCell(0);
   cell2.innerHTML='<a href="" onclick="removerow('+rowCount+'); return   false;">deleterow</a>';

   var cell2 = row.insertCell(1);
   cell2.innerHTML='price';

   var cell3 = row.insertCell(2);
   cell3.innerHTML='name';

}
```

here is my removing row function

```
function removerow(i){      
    var table = document.getElementById('baskettbl');
    table.deleteRow(i);
 }
```

my problem is when i remove a row if that row is in the middle of my table it will mess up the indexing cuz i define removerow argument when i creat each row

```
   var rowCount = table.rows.length;
   var row = table.insertRow(rowCount);
   var cell2 = row.insertCell(0);
   cell2.innerHTML='<a href="" onclick="removerow('+rowCount+'); return false; />
```

like if i have 5 rows and and i remove row[3] i will end up with 4 rows but my last row button is still going to pass 5 to the removerow function and of course there is no row[5]

so i thought i should re index all of the rows by simply

```
 function removerow(i){

     var table = document.getElementById('baskettbl');
        table.deleteRow(i);
     }
     var rowCount = table.rows.length;

      for(i=0 , i<= rowCount ; i++){
     var cell = 'cell'+i;
      cell.innerHTML='<a href="" onclick="removerow('+0+'); return false; />  
      }
```

but i need to set the td id in the numeric whey so i can change their innerhtml like this
so here is my questions :

1.how can i set the attribute like id to the created td so i can get their values later? here is how i create them

```
var cell2 = row.insertCell(0);
```

2.i findout about rowIndex property which apparently returns the row index

function removerow(x)
{
alert("Row index is: " + x.rowIndex);
}
so that is going to make my job easy and i don't need to recreate all the indexes but how can i pass the clicked row 'this' to the the function ? here is how i pass the index

```
var cell2 = row.insertCell(0);
cell2.innerHTML='<a href="" onclick="removerow('+rowCount+'); />
```

and also i use dreamweaver cs5 and it doesn't seems to recognize rowIndex

Comment: Why not use jQuery? If you are the wheel re-inventor kind of coder, please tell me when your theory, about the way the wheel should roll, will be ready.

Comment: i'm sorry i should have said that it's a assignment for school i cant use any framework

Comment: Whichever school is teaching you this stuff is years behind with standards. I see nothing else, but horrible coding standards. I don't see any interesting POC here, as to why they want you to do it this way. I would suggest you start thinking to work with objects in JavaScript, and not do an unnecessary indexing on a table. Pass the specific object `this` to the function as in `doMagic(this)`, and work with the passed object not with the index.

Comment: well actually it's a javascript for beginners class and they trying to get us feel comfortable with the syntax so we have to build a one page e-shop only using javascript but we are going to start oop programing and frameworks soon . anyway thanx for reply

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Then get the index dynamically and don't set it when you create it:

```
function createrow(){  
   document.getElementById('totaltd').innerHTML = total;

   var table = document.getElementById('baskettbl'),
       rowCount = table.rows.length,
       row = table.insertRow(rowCount),
       cell = row.insertCell(0),
       a = document.createElement('a');

   a.href = '#';
   a.innerHTML = 'deleterow';
   a.onclick = function() {
       // `this` refers to the `a` element.
       removerow(this.parentNode.parentNode.rowIndex);
       return false;
   };

   cell.appendChild(a);

   cell = row.insertCell(1);
   cell.innerHTML='price';

   cell = row.insertCell(2);
   cell.innerHTML='name';

   // still needed for IE memory leak? Don't know...
   table = row = cell = a = null;
};
```

Setting the click event handler via JavaScript is more readable anyway (well, you could also just use `this.parentNode....` in the HTML string).

---

The code above should do what you want (if you have questions about it, just comment). Nevertheless I wanted to answer your questions:

> how can i set the attribute like id to the created td so i can get their values later?

An important thing to know is that there is a difference between *HTML attributes* and *DOM properties*. [These answers describe it quite well](https://stackoverflow.com/q/5874652/218196), although it is originally about jQuery (but that does not matter).

Anyway, you already know how to set the `innerHTML` and you can do so similar for `id`:

```
cell.id = "something";
```

Have a look at the [*DOM element reference*](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/DOM/element).

> but how can i pass the clicked row 'this' to the the function

I more or less showed this in the code above. Inside the event handler, `this` refers to the element you bound the event to. We know that it is an `a` element which is a child of a `td` element, which itself is a child of a `tr` element. So to get the corresponding row, we can access `this.parentNode.parentNode`.

---

For further information regarding JavaScript, [have a look at the `javascript` tag information page](https://stackoverflow.com/tags/javascript/info). There you will find a lot of useful links to introductions about various JavaScript related topics.
Especially have a look at the [articles about event handling at quirksmode.org](http://www.quirksmode.org/js/introevents.html).

Comment: wow thanx man everything is clear the reason i asked for setting id to td is that dreamweaver automatically generates the list of the propertys that i can use by putting "." after element and it didn't give me anything for so i thought maybe it doesn't work like that  for table columns  i have another question how can i get the value of the "price" columns of the deleted row on the deleterow function ? something like 

this.parentNode.parentNode.Cell(2).innerHTML

Comment: @max: Do you change that value? Because you initially set it to `price` ;) Anyway, if it is always the second cell, you can get it via `this.parentNode.parentNode.cells[1].innerHTML` (better store a reference to the row, like `var row = this.parentNode.parentNode;`). Have a look at the [`HTMLTableRowElement` documentation](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/DOM/HTMLTableRowElement). Btw. Dreamweaver is more for designers, it is not necessarily good for really developing websites. And don't rely on code completion. It makes your life easier but also learn what properties are available ;).

Answer (score 0):

Try this I hope this helps you.

```
 function createrow(){

       document.getElementById('totaltd').innerHTML = total;

       var table = document.getElementById('baskettbl');
       var rowCount = table.rows.length;
       var row = table.insertRow(rowCount);
       row.id = "row_"+rowCount;
       var cell2 = row.insertCell(0);
       cell2.innerHTML='<a href="" onclick="removerow('+rowCount+'); return   false;">deleterow</a>';

       var cell2 = row.insertCell(1);
       cell2.innerHTML='price';

       var cell3 = row.insertCell(2);
       cell3.innerHTML='name';

    }




function removerow(i){      
    var table = document.getElementById('baskettbl');
    table.removeChild(document.getElementById("row_"+i));
 }
```